# how to chain methods using variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const persons = {
  p1: {
    first: "Yassine",
    last: "Boutabia",       
  },
  p2: {
    first: "Md Jahidul Hasan",
    last: "Mozumder",
  },
  p3: {
    first: "Md Feroj",
    last: "Ahmod",
  },
}

booYa = () => {
  var val = "first"; //just an idea came to me
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in persons) {
    if (persons.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      arr.push(persons[key]);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr[0].val);
}
```

the variable `arr` represents the `persons` objects as array here. When i write `console.log(arr[0].first);` it outputs the `first` of `p1` which is `Yassine`. So far so good.
Now i am trying to do get this first from a variable. **I want to put the `first` or `last` in a variable** and chain it at the end of `arr[0]` so that i get that value. How can it be done?

Comment: `arr[0][variable]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[]`

```
console.log(arr[0][val]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** to transform the array however you want and then display.

```js
persons
  .map(p => `${p.name} ${p.last}`)
  .forEach(fullname => console.log(fullname))
```